# How set PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range") as a variable

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog

I am trying to implement a return value from a HTML dialog [from here](https://There%20are%20two%20onClick%20events%20in%20a%20modal%20dialog%20into%20one%20onClick%20event%20Google%20script)

have

```
function saveRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", `${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()}!${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()}`);
  ss.toast(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range"));
}

function launchSaveRangeDialog() {
  const html = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <base target="_top"> <title>My Html</title> </head> <body> <h1>Please Select a Range and Press Save</h1> <br><input type="button" value="Save" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((v) => google.script.host.close()).saveRange();"> </body> </html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Save Dailog");
}
```

Why can I not do this

```
function saveRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", `${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()}!${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()}`);
 
let x = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range");

let y = somefunction(x);

//OR even

console.log(x)
}
```

Very confused by this.

Comment: I've replicated both codes and it is working as it is. May I know what is your expected output or are you encountering an error message?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function saveMyRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", `${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()}!${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()}`);
  let x = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range");
  console.log(x)
}

Execution log
3:53:29 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:53:29 PM  Info    Sheet0!B4
3:53:31 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

And this works also:

```
function saveMyRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", `${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()}!${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()}`);
  let x = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range");
  console.log(x);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x).getValues()).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
}

Execution log
3:57:48 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:57:48 PM  Info    Sheet0!A1:J12
3:57:48 PM  Info    [["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","2023-10-17T06:00:00.000Z","","","","","","","",""],
["",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""]]
3:57:50 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)